# FileNotFoundException: `generated/source/apollo/generatedIR/main`

Tags: gradle, apollo

I try to generate my graphql schema using gradle apollo `generateApolloClasses`. So the first step is to `generateMainApolloIR` and it is working fine. It is generating a `MainAPI.json` under
`/generated/source/apollo/generatedIR/main/src/main/graphql/client/backend/MainAPI.json`. But the `generateApolloClasses` is failing with:

```
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/mctigg/Documents/Repositories/generated/source/apollo/generatedIR/main (Is a directory)
```

So it is looking into the wrong path! This is my gradle config:

```
apollo {
    nullableValueType = "javaOptional"
    outputPackageName = "generated.client.backend"
}

task generateBackendSchemaJson(type: ApolloSchemaIntrospectionTask) {
    url = 'src/main/graphql/client/backend/schema.graphqls'
    output = 'src/main/graphql/client/backend/schema.json'
}

tasks.findByName('generateMainApolloIR').dependsOn(['generateBackendSchemaJson'])
```

So how can I configure `generateApolloClasses` to look into:

`/generated/source/apollo/generatedIR/main/src/main/graphql/client/backend/`

Instead of

`/generated/source/apollo/generatedIR/main/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should set schema file path as follows:

```
apollo {
  schemaFilePath = "/generated/source/apollo/generatedIR/main/src/main/graphql/client/backend/schema.json"
  nullableValueType = "javaOptional"
  outputPackageName = "generated.client.backend"
}
```